# vlc plays only grey screen with some moving parts

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vlc-media-player, updates, media-player

I have got some problem with vlc media player after some updates on ubuntu 12.04. Audio and subtitles works fine, but the picture is just grey. I have tried some other output settings 
x11 video output (xcb), but it seems still not working. Do anyone have some ideas? Cheers!

Comment: What kind of source video are you using?

Comment: dvd video media